# Facebook Flow - how to return a type casted property from deeply nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a flow type that's a deeply nested object.  I want to create a function that extracts a specific property, if that property exists on an object of that type, and that property value is of that type:

Viewable on try flow [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAieeOMWAcngM4Z4AmYAvGAN6phgDatATgJYA7AOYBdAFxg+Q4WAA+REmUo069VAF8A3OigBXQQGMM-OILDC8GQnGHUAFPSXkqtBpOKkXqhgEpJAPyeyq5qbBxgvFZ6vOaOzipu9AB09LbUHgmhfjoa6DBWUnAAtngAKgAWMgDq-BgVNnbM4ZxpdpLsnJzUJVZVIgCiMNR4kgDkWDRjEXl5qAUYkTR6MIssltbp9j2llTV1Dem+WkA)

```
/* @flow */

type DeeplyNested = {
  [string]: string | DeeplyNested
};

function getDogs(deeplyNested: DeeplyNested): ?DeeplyNested {
  return (deeplyNested.dogs: DeeplyNested);
}

let someThingWithDogs = {
  dogs: {
    somethingElse: 'yes'
  }
}

let result = getDogs(someThingWithDogs);
```

I get the error:

> return (deeplyNested.dogs: DeeplyNested);
>                ^ string.
>
> This type is incompatible with return (deeplyNested.dogs: DeeplyNested);
>                                   ^ object type

Is there a way to check first if the property is of that type, then cast and return that property?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, just need to check if it's an object:

```
function getDogs(deeplyNested: DeeplyNested): ?DeeplyNested {
  if (typeof deeplyNested.dogs === 'object') return deeplyNested.dogs;
}
```

Comment: There are now docs for this to obtain the return type at author time. See `$Call<T, F>` https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call